# Are ingame content identification questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know game identifications are off topic, but would I be allowed to ask for a certain content ingame? For example "Hows the level with the tall trees called in [game]?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This sort of question is perfectly cromulent.

In general, "What is the name of this thing I am clearly and specifically pointing to" is always fine. "What is this thing I am describing which I kind of sort of remember but have forgotten" is not.

Comment: ***Cromulent*** - Used in an ironical sense to mean legitimate, and therefore, in reality, spurious and not at all legitimate. Assumes common knowledge of the inherent Simpsons reference. - [*U.D.*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cromulent)

Comment: I take issue with that UD definition. Cromulent is widely used sans irony.

Comment: For people who don't know what it means, that's the first Google result, hence the first (and probably only) definition they'll read.

Comment: It's the second result for me. First is the more accurate [Wikitionary.](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent)

Comment: meta answers are always mysterious, in my case it would be your second example, but referring to in-game content, not a game itself. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181523/searching-for-an-instance-name